# How can I prevent BufferManager / PooledBufferManager in my WCF client app from wasting memory?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, buffer-manager

Analyzing a WCF client application (that I did not write and still do not know too much about) that talks to a bunch of services via SOAP and after running for a couple of days will throw an OutOfMemoryException, I found out that .net's PooledBufferManager will never ever release unused buffers, even when the app runs out of memory, leading to OOMEs.

This of course being in accordance with the spec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405814.aspx

> The pool and its buffers are [...] destroyed when the buffer pool is
>   reclaimed by garbage collection.

Please feel free to answer to only a single of the questions below, as I have a bunch of questions, some of a more general nature, and some specific to our app's use of the BufferManager.

First a couple of general questions about the (default Pooled)BufferManager:

**1)** In a environment where we have GC, why would we need a BufferManager that will hold on to unused memory, even when that leads to OOME? I know, there is BufferManager.Clear(), which you can use to *manually* get rid off all buffers - if you have access to the BufferManager, that is. See further down for why I don't seem to have access.

**2)** Despite of MS' claim that "This process is much faster than creating and destroying a buffer every time you need to use one.", shouldn't they leave that up to the GC (and its LOH for example) and optimize the GC instead?

**3)** When doing a BufferManager.Take(33 * 1024 * 1024), I will get a buffer of 64M, as the PooledBufferManager will cache that buffer for later reuse, which might - well, in my case it isn't and therefore it's pure waste of memory - be that, say, 34M, or 50M, or 64M, are needed. So was it wise to create a potentially very wasteful BufferManager like this, that is used (by default, I assume) by HttpsChannelFactory? I'm failing to see how the performance for memory allocation should matter, especially when we are talking about WCF and network services that the application will talk to every 10 seconds TOPS, normally many more seconds or even minutes.

Now some more specific questions related to our application's use of BufferManagers. The app connects to a couple of different WCF services. For each of them we maintain a connection pool for the http connections, as connections may occur concurrently.

Inspecting the single biggest object in one heap dump, a 64M byte array that had only been used once in our app at initialization time and is not needed afterwards, as the response from the service is that big only at initialization time, which btw. is typical for many applications I have used, even though that could be subject to opimization (caching to disk etc.). A GC root analysis in WinDbg yields the following (I sanitized the names of our proprietary classes to 'MyServiceX', etc.):

```
0:000:x86> !gcroot -nostacks 193e1000
DOMAIN(00B8CCD0):HANDLE(Pinned):4d1330:Root:0e5b9c50(System.Object[])->
035064f0(MyServiceManager)->
0382191c(MyHttpConnectionPool`1[[MyServiceX, MyLib]])->
03821988(System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[[MyServiceX, MyLib]])->
038219a8(System.Object[])->
039c05b4(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy)->
039c0578(System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy)->
039c0494(System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel)->
039bee30(System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory+ServiceChannelFactoryOverRequest)->
039beea4(System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsChannelFactory)->
039bf2c0(System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager+PooledBufferManager)->
039c02f4(System.Object[])->
039bff24(System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager+PooledBufferManager+BufferPool)->
039bff44(System.ServiceModel.SynchronizedPool`1[[System.Byte[], mscorlib]])->
039bffa0(System.ServiceModel.SynchronizedPool`1+GlobalPool[[System.Byte[], mscorlib]])->
039bffb0(System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[[System.Byte[], mscorlib]])->
12bda2bc(System.Byte[][])->
193e1000(System.Byte[])
```

Looking at gc roots for other byte arrays managed by a BufferManager reveals that other services (not 'MyServiceX') have different BufferPool instances, so each one is wasting their own memory, they are not even sharing the waste.

**4)** Are we doing something wrong here? I'm not a WCF expert by any means, so could we make the various HttpsChannelFactory instances all use the same BufferManager?

**5)** Or maybe even better, could we just tell all HttpsChannelFactory instances NOT to use BufferManagers at all and ask the GC to do its god-damn job, which is 'managing memory'?

**6)** If questions 4) and 5) can't be answered, could I get access to the BufferManager of all HttpsChannelFactory instances and manually call .Clear() on them - this is far from on optimal solution, but it would already help, in my case, it would free not only the aformentioned 64M, but 64M + 32M + 16M + 8M + 4M + 2M just in one service instance! So that alone would make my app last much longer without running into memory problems (and no, we don't have a memory leak issue, other than BufferManager, although we do consume a lot of memory and accumulate a lot of data over the course of many days, but that's not the issue here)

Comment: @dlev's edit: Thanks for removing humour. I appreciate it.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: @John Saunders - and copying the boilerplate into every single one of these separate questions? That doesn't seem to make sense. Even though I split the questions up, they are all related to the same problem. One might argue to split up at least the "general" and the "specific" questions, but still, even the general questions refer to my specific situation, so...

Comment: learn how we do things on [SO]. We do one question per question. They may refer to each other. We also downvote questions we have a problem with, as I'm about to do now.

Comment: Well, John, I addressed your 'one question per question' issue in my last comment, I think.

Comment: Not really; you just gave your reason for believing you're a special case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 4) Are we doing something wrong here? I'm not a WCF expert by any
>   means, so could we make the various HttpsChannelFactory instances all
>   use the same BufferManager?
>
> 5) Or maybe even better, could we just tell all HttpsChannelFactory
>   instances NOT to use BufferManagers at all and ask the GC to do its
>   god-damn job, which is 'managing memory'?

I guess one way of addressing those 2 questions could be changing the TransferMode from 'buffered' to 'streamed'. Will have to investigate, as 'streamed' mode has a couple of limitations and I might not be able to use it.

**Update:** It actually works great! My memory consumption in buffered mode during startup of the app was **630M** at peak times, and reduced to **470M** when fully loaded. After switching to streamed mode, memory consumption does not show a temporary peak and when fully loaded, consumption is at only **270M**!

Btw., this was a one-line change in the client app code for me. I just had to add this line:

```
httpsTransportBindingElement.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse;
```

Comment: I know this question is a bit old but I thought I would ask a quick question. I too am NOT a WCF expert. I'm having the same problem and would like to use streaming. Is this really possible to do on the client side? I have a service reference and it automagically builds the client class code for me but where do I attach this binding element to the client object? I'm not finding a property as of yet that would allow me to apply one.

Comment: @jlafay If you don't programmatically create BindingElements etc. you should have a look at your config files (for the server it would be Web.config, not sure if for the client side it's app.config or where the WCF stuff is stored). Have a look at e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/03/31/565558.aspx for the elements responsible to change to streaming mode.

Answer (score 11):

I believe I have answer to your question #5:

> 5) Or maybe even better, could we just tell all HttpsChannelFactory
>   instances NOT to use     BufferManagers at all and ask the GC to do
>   its god-damn job, which is 'managing memory'?

There is a MaxBufferPoolSize binding parameter, which controls max size of buffers in BufferManager. Setting it to 0 will disable buffering, and GCBufferManager will be created instead of pooled one - and it will GC allocated buffers as soon as message is processed, as in your question.

This article discusses [WCF memory buffer management](http://obsessivelycurious.blogspot.ru/2008/04/wcf-memory-buffer-management.html) in greater detail.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link. In my case, migrating to `TransferMode.Streamed` solved the issue to my full satisfaction, as it not only solved the cleanup issues of those buffers, but got rid of their creation altogether.

Answer (score 4):

As John says it would be easier to answer only one question instead of writing an essay. But here is what I think

> 1) In a environment where we have GC, why would we need a
>   BufferManager

You seem to misunderstand the concept of GC and buffers. GC works with reference typed objects and frees memory if it detects that an object is a vertex (point or node) of a graph and it doesn't have any valid edges (lines or connections) to other vertices. Buffers are just some temporary storage for temporary array of raw data. For example, if you need to send a WCF application level message and its current size is larger than the transport level message size, WCF will do it in a few transport messages. On the receiver size, WCF will wait until the full application level message arrives and only then it would pass the message for processing (unless it's a streaming binding). The temporary transport messages are *buffered* - stored somewhere in memory on the receiver's end. As creating of new buffers for any new messages in this example can get very expansive, .NET provides you with a buffer management class that is responsible for pooling and sharing buffers.

> 2) Despite of MS' claim that "This process is much faster than
>   creating and destroying a buffer every time you need to use one.",
>   shouldn't they leave that up to the GC (and its LOH for example) and
>   optimize the GC instead?

No they should not. Buffers and GC have nothing in common (unless you want to destroy the buffer every time, in the context of the sample, that is a design flaw). They have different responsibilities and address different problems.

> 3) The app connects to a couple of different WCF services. For each of
>   them we maintain a connection pool for the http connections

HTTP binding is not design to handle large payload like 64Mb, consider changing the binding to more appropriate one. If you use the message of that sie, WCF will not pass it unless the whole 64Mb are fully received. Thus if you have 10 concurrent connections your buffer size will be 640Mb.

For your other questions, please post another question on SO with some code and your WCF configuration. It will be easier to find where the problem is. Maybe the buffers aren't cleared because they are used inappropriately, you should consider the amount of testing that has been done on GC and WCF and the amount of testing that's been performed on a legacy project - follow the Occam's razor.

Comment: I do understand the difference between GC and buffers. I don't understand where one would use buffers, rather than leaving it up to the GC. The GC should allow for quick allocation and automatic release of memory, that's its job. It should be fast enough to allocate a byte array per request. Of course if you write code that, say, iterates over a stream, reading it chunk-wise, you'll allocate a buffer manually, and only once, and then fill and re-fill it until done. No need for buffer managers. Do you have a use case for buffer managers? I don't see WCF requests/responses as being one.

Comment: As to "changing the binding to more appropriate one", see the answer to myself. Changing the transfer mode to 'streamed' seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265299 and will close this one as soon as I can accept my own answer (which answers only the specific part of that question) or some better answer appears, whatever comes first.

Comment: Regarding your 'if you have 10 concurrent connections your buffer size will be 640MB' statement - the problem is even bigger in case you use 10 different services (in my app, it's 6 different services). Then the connections don't even need to be concurrent, they can occur at any time during the life of the app, as buffer managers are created per service and they never free their buffers, as explained in my question.

Comment: Are you talking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx ? That would be about the server-side only, if I'm not mistaken. I just edited my question to reflect what might not have been clear: I'm talking about a client application. In any event, our services are set to InstanceContextMode.Single.

Comment: @Eugene The problem is not in the buffer manager, the problem is in the server side instance, which is singleton, which brings you severe memory and CPU problems. All the requests are dealt with by only one object on the server, so forget about concurrency and multithreading. All your calls are buffered on the server side and memory is released once one request is fully processed. By setting the transfer mode to streamed you allowed the server to start processing message before it is fully received. Still the server cannot work on other requests, before this one is done. Change instance mngmt

Comment: I only changed the client, leading to vast improvements in the client. Again - this question is not about the server side, and that my client-side only changes lead to aforementioned vast improvements should be proof enough that it is working.